# Error: Image: asset with ID "1" could not be found. Please check the image source or packager

Tags: react-native, background

I'm new to react native and I'm following a tutorial to learn the language.
I'm now trying to set a background image using ImageBackground.

WelcomeScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from 'react-native-web';

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
    return (
        <ImageBackground 
            style={styles.background}
            source={require("../assets/background.jpg")}
        ></ImageBackground>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1
    }
})

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import WelcomeScreen from './app/screens/WelcomeScreen';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <WelcomeScreen />
  );
}
```

Now I get this error: `Error: Image: asset with ID "1" could not be found. Please check the image source or packager.`

I have a **app** folder in in my projectfolder. In this app folder I have the assets folder and a screens folder. The WelcomeScreen.js is in the screens folder. The background.jpg is in the assets folder and the App.js is in the main/project folder.

I can't seem to find any way to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your module import from `react-native-web` to just `react-native`

**WelcomeScreen.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      style={styles.background}
      source={require("../assets/background.png")}
    ></ImageBackground>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

You do not need to add `./app` to your WelcomeScreen.js file path

**App.js**

```js
import WelcomeScreen from "./screens/WelcomeScreen";

export default function App() {
  return <WelcomeScreen />;
}
```

Hope this helps!